# How to get an index used with OR in statement

Tags: sql, firebird

I have SQL with params passed by user. User can pass some id or -1, what mean "nevermind".
It's possible to write query like below, but can using index?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    ((col1 = :param1) OR (:param1 = -1))
    AND ((col2 = :param2) OR (:param2 = -1))
    AND col3 STARTING 'A'
```

`col1`, `col2` and `col3` are indexed. In FB 2.x using `OR` never use index for col1 or col2. In FB 3 only if first (or second) conditions exist that can use index (PLAN index and natural), but with last condition stop using index for col1/2.

How can I write SQL without using PLAN and can use index for `col1/2` and stay possibility to "off" condition by passing `-1`?

Comment: why not construct different SQL for the query on the client ( or even in SP ), based on filter parameters?

Comment: SQL is write in interface (not in code) and must be universal. Something like IBExpert, but SQL wrote once (f.ex. by super-user) and will be not change every use with different parameters.

Comment: Wrapping the logic into `EXECUTE BLOCK` might be an option...

Comment: @Dżyszla . . . Construct the `where` clause dynamically and add it to the query.  Conditions with `or` are much harder to optimize than conditions only with `and`s.

Comment: give super-user option to provide variants of sql sub-parts. Or a constructor like one in IBExpert

Comment: No, no... Super-user create some query. Application build for this (base on query params) interface, that use "normal" user. Super-user write query once and wants give for others option to specify (>0) or not (-1) filter. So must create query for both cases.

Comment: Exectly, so the application should have way to take from the super-user not the fixed once for all query, but a template, from which slightly variating queries might be built

Comment: PS AFAIR one can explicitly specify execution plan in SQL statement, but then there would be no warranty the user-enforced plan would be optimal or correct. Afterall, you make sorting on *three* columns, it is not clear that merging indices #1 and #2 then nat-scanning over col3 would always be better than first reducing by col3 and then nat-scanning over col1 and col2

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite a condition like

```
(col1 = :param1) OR (:param1 = -1)
```

as

```
col1 = case when :param1 = -1 then col1 else :param1 end
```

Since it's a single expression, you can also safely delete all the brackets, which makes the query easier to read.

Comment: Still PLAN (NATURAL) and read all records - that not work in Firebird :(

Comment: I don't think a `case` expression will *increase* the likelihood of using an index.